# devise_inviable, delete pending invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I have a Rails app in which `Users` can invite `Members` to `Teams`, to do this I tried to use the gem `devise_invitable`. It have worked fine so far, but I have run into some issues when it comes to deleting pending invitations. If the user for example typed the wrong email address, I want him / her to be able to delete the invitation. But I can't get it to work. My routes is set up like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations", invitations: "users/invitations"}

resources :teams do
  resources :invitations
  [...]
```

The relevant parts of my custom `"users/invitations"` (placed in controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb) controller looks like this:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

  before_action :set_invitation, only: [:destroy]

  def destroy
    This currently never gets called
    team = @invitation.team
    @invitation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_team_path(team) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I try to link the the `destroy` action like this:

```
= link_to team_invitation_path(@team, invitation), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this invitation?'}, class: "label label-danger label-pill pull-xs-right" do
  = icon("trash-o")
```

My `Invitation` model looks like this:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :recipient_email
  enum status: [ :pending, :accepted ]

end
```

I currently get the following error when I click the link:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant InvitationsController
```

I'm not completely sure how to solve it or what I can have missed. Not 100% that `devise_invitable` is the right gem for my need right now.

Any ideas on what I can do to make it work?

My relevant routes after running `rake routes`:

```
# These were here before as well
accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                                        
users/invitations#edit
remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                                            users/invitations#destroy
user_invitation POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                                                                                 users/invitations#create
new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                                             users/invitations#new

# My custom / new team invitation routes
team_invitations 
GET    /teams/:team_id/invitations(.:format)                                                                        users/invitations#index 
POST    /teams/:team_id/invitations(.:format)                                                                        users/invitations#create new_team_invitation 
GET    /teams/:team_id/invitations/new(.:format)                                                                      users/invitations#new edit_team_invitation 
GET    /teams/:team_id/invitations/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 users/invitations#edit team_invitation 
GET    /teams/:team_id/invitations/:id(.:format)                                                                     users/invitations#show 
PATCH  /teams/:team_id/invitations/:id(.:format)                                                                     users/invitations#update 
PUT    /teams/:team_id/invitations/:id(.:format)                                                                    users/invitations#update 
DELETE /teams/:team_id/invitations/:id(.:format)                                                                  users/invitations#destroy
```

The new routes point to e.g. `users/invitations#destroy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to point to `Users::InvitationsController`, which is different than `InvitationsController` -- which doesn't exist.  You need to inform `routes.rb` about this:

```
resources :teams do
  resources :invitations, module: 'users'
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to help somewhat, but I unfortunately ran into another issue. I now get the following error instead: `NoMethodError in Users::InvitationsController#destroy undefined method name for nil:NilClass`.

 `# Proxy to devise map name
  def resource_name
    devise_mapping.name
  end
  alias :scope_name :resource_name`

Comment: So, sounds like it's reaching the method like you wanted, but then bad things ensue?  Might need to go a different direction them.  Post `rake routes` (prior to the change above); that will let me know if that change is advisable or if something else unrelated is going on.

Comment: Actually my `destroy` action is not getting called, instead on of `devise_invitable` methods is getting called, `def resource_name`, and the error says that `devise_mapping.name` is nil (devise_mapping is nil).

Comment: @Anders Ok. Post the results of `rake routes`

Comment: I have updated my original question with the new routes.

Comment: Looks like the route you want is `remove_user_invitation`.  But it's a `GET`, not a `DELETE`, and you have to pass the `invitation_token` as a query parameter, i.e. `/users/invitation/remove?invitation_token={the_token}`. Try adding that to your view.

Comment: Tried that before but then I got the error / alert that my invitation_token was invalid, i used invitation.invitation_token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110190/discussion-between-gogocarl-and-anders).

Comment: Will have to go to bed now, but maybe tomorrow, thank you'

Comment: GL.  Pretty sure combination of those two should do you, but ping me here if it doesn't and I'll see if I can clarify any specifics.

Comment: Decided to roll with my own invitation system and not rely on the `devise_invitable` gem, will award you the correct answer anyhow for the good help and effort.